# How is 'outDir' in tsconfig.json resolved?

Tags: typescript, path, output, tsconfig

Does baseUrl or current working directory affect it?
And, more generally, where is this documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be documented anywhere, but it's resolved relative to the directory of `tsconfig.json` file, and it's not affected by `baseUrl` - `baseUrl` is for module resolution only.

[The source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L985), slightly reformatted:

```
    const result = parseJsonText(configFileName, configFileText);
    const cwd = host.getCurrentDirectory();
    return parseJsonSourceFileConfigFileContent(
        result, 
        host, 
        getNormalizedAbsolutePath(getDirectoryPath(configFileName), cwd),
        optionsToExtend, 
        getNormalizedAbsolutePath(configFileName, cwd)
    );
```

The third argument for [`parseJsonSourceFileConfigFileContent`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L1518) is the base for resolving relative paths in `tsconfig.json`, and as you see it comes from `configFileName` which is the name of `tsconfig.json` file.